# Being + Turning

Tags: passive-voice, gerunds, participles

Please correct me if the following sentence is wrong:

> Let's save our children from **being turning** into professional criminals.

What is wrong with using: being + turning ?

Answer (score 1):

The passive requires the past participle:

....from being *turned* into criminals

Answer (score 0):

After the preposition can follow a noun or a gerund, so it would be

- from turning into criminals or from becoming criminals.

A gerund consists of the verb + ing. There is never a double formation as 
being turning.

Your exemple sentence doesn't sound as something one might really say or hear. Sounds like a sentence made up by yourself.